# Priority of quarkus injections in @QuarkusTest

Tags: quarkus

I have problem with order in integration tests, because I need to load one class before others, but it's currently random.

Is any possibilities to use something that would say to load it first (during running app context) in Quarkus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not possible to order the execution of the Classes in tests. They execute randomly.

I know for sure that you can order the execution of the test methods inside a class.

That said, I used one strategy in one application where I needed to **start a process as the first step of my tests**.

Inside my test package, I created one class with `ApplicationScoped` and created one method with the `@Observes StartupEvent StartupEvent` parameter.

When I execute `mvn test`, this method is the first to be executed.

### Class with a method to start my initializing process

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import io.quarkus.runtime.ShutdownEvent;
import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AcceptorStarter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AcceptorStarter.class.getName());

    @Inject
    AcceptorServer acceptorServer;

    // Starts automatically with application
    public void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent StartupEvent) {
        LOG.info("Starting FIX Acceptor to allow tests");
        acceptorServer.init();
    }

    // Ends automatically with application
    public void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent shutdownEvent) {
        LOG.info("Finishing FIX Acceptor");
        acceptorServer.stop();
    }

}
```

### Ordering the execution of methods

You can order the execution of the test methods, like this:

```java
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;

@QuarkusTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class PropertiesRestTest {

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void getQuickfixSessionSettings() {
        given()
          .when()
          .get("/properties/quickfix-session-settings")
          .then()
             .statusCode(200);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void putQuickfixSessionSettings() {
        given()
          .body(appProperties.getQuickfixSessionSettings())
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
          .when().put("/properties/quickfix-session-settings")
          .then()
             .statusCode(200);
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public void restauraQuickfixSessionSettings() {
        given()
          .when()
          .put("/properties/restaura-quickfix-session-settings-original")
          .then()
             .statusCode(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: Strategy with @StartupEvent has been solution which I needed! Really thank you